# create project in ionic with --v2 and framework are 3

Tags: ionic-framework

I created a project with

ionic start navigationAppv2 blank --v2

but when I use ionic info say:

Ionic Framework Version: 3.0.0

how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean but I suspect you want to downgrade your Ionic framework version? If so, you just need to update your `package.json` to `"ionic-angular": "2.3.0"` for instance. The below is an extract of my `package.json` file running on the latest v2 version:

`"@angular/common": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.4.8",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/device": "3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/local-notifications": "3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.4.4",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.0",
    "ionic-angular": "2.3.0"`